# AngularJS : Initialize app with asynchronous data with csrf token from api as a constant

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers, csrf

I wish to query the API to get a CSRF token. Then set this token in the header of all HTTP requests.

Before I set the CSRF token as a constant for the angularJS app, I am experiencing some difficulties.

```
app.run(['$http', function($http) {

    var csrf = $http( { method: 'GET', url: 'api/csrf' })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log("CSRF Success: " + data.token);
                return data.token;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log("CSRF ERROR: " + data);
            });

        console.log("CSRF TOKEN: " + csrf);
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = csrf;
}]);
```

When I run my application, I get the following in my browser console:

```
CSRF TOKEN: [object Object] scripts.js?v=1400582971:32411
GET http://testapp/api/v1/supplier 400 (Bad Request) scripts.js?v=1400582971:17571
CSRF Success: zD7TrQWQWma0eHYtzM8NcgbvitB9XJzTCegjAVMg scripts.js?v=1400582971:32404
```

There are several things wrong here...

- Firstly, `CSRF Success` should be outputted before `CSRF TOKEN`.
- Secondly, `CSRF TOKEN: [object Object]` should be `CSRF TOKEN: zD7TrQWQWma0eHYtzM8NcgbvitB9XJzTCegjAVMg`
- Thirdly, the reason for the 400 (Bad Request) is because the headers sent in the get request are `X-Csrf-Token:[object Object]`. The header should be `X-Csrf-Token:zD7TrQWQWma0eHYtzM8NcgbvitB9XJzTCegjAVMg`

I don't want the variable `csrf` to be an object. It needs to be an actual string value.

Once I have this working, I am looking to extract the http request out and do something like the following:

```
app.factory("CSRF_TOKEN", function($http) {

    var token;

    $http( { method: 'GET', url: 'api/csrf' })
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log("CSRF Success: " + data.token);
                    token = data.token;
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log("CSRF ERROR: " + data);
                });
});

app.run(['$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = CSRF_TOKEN.token;
}]);
```

**MY SOLUTION TO PROBLEM:**

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/api/csrf", false);
xhReq.send(null);

app.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", xhReq.responseText);

app.run(['$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {

    console.log("Injected CSRF: " + CSRF_TOKEN);

    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
}]);
```

Comment: Problem Solved... See updated solution. I am all ears for better alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your original solution didn't work because you are expecting the `$http.get` to return your token but in fact this method returns a `promise`. The actual data, your token, is returned asynchronously via the the `success` function.

Your original code should probably look something like this:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'api/csrf' })
        .success(function(response) {
            var token = response.data.token;
            console.log("CSRF Success: " + token);
            $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = token;
            //carry on with processing
        })
        .error(function(response) {
            console.log("CSRF ERROR: " + response.status);
});
```